Перегрузка метода одного из предка при множественном наследовании
Есть наследник от двух предков. У обоих предков есть метод с определённым именем. Мне в наследнике нужно назначить (перегрузить) метод с таким же именем, который бы дублировал один из этих методов предка. Чтобы, вызывая метод у наследника, выполнялся одноимённый метод одного из предков.
Я нагромоздил вот такую конструкцию
class Base1 {
private:
    int data;
public:
    int const & Data() const { return data; }
};

class Base2 {
private:
    std::vector<int> data;
public:
    Base2() : data{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 } {}

    std::vector<int> const & Data() const & { return           data ; }
    std::vector<int>      && Data()      && { return std::move(data); }
};

class Derived: public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
    std::vector<int> const & Data() const & { return Base2::Data(); }
    std::vector<int>      && Data()      && { return std::forward<Base2>(*this).Data(); }
};

constexpr auto WWW() {
    return Derived().Data().size(); // тут вызывается Base2::Data() &&
}

int main()
{
    Derived obj{};
    auto v1 = obj.Data(); // тут вызывается Base2::Data() const
    auto v2 = Derived().Data(); // тут вызывается Base2::Data() &&
    auto s = WWW();
    auto v3 = Base2().Data();
}

Исправлено еще раз
Вроде работает верно (извиняюсь, сам себя обманул, а потом забыл где. исправил). Но не является ли второй метод (Data() &&) излишним?
Может быть, раз уж я всегда возвращаю только константную ссылку на поле-член, нет смысла писать второй вариант метода с &&? Или же без Data() && будут лишние копирования на v2 = Derived().Data();? Не смог по ассемблеру понять.


Или же без Data() && будут лишние копирования на v2 = Derived().Data();? Не смог по ассемблеру понять.

Не нужно разбираться в ассемблере чтобы понять. Нужно поставить вместо возвращаемого типа свой класс, с логированием в копирующем и перемещающем конструкторе. Лишние копирования действительно будут.

Еще, std::forward тут не очень хорошо смотрится. Это условный move, поэтому не в шаблонах обычно пишут или сразу std::move(), или ничего. Я бы написал так: std::move(*this).Base2::Data(). Или так: static_cast<Base2 &&>(*this).Data().

Еще, можно в потомке Data вообще не определять, а просто сделать using Base2::Data;.

Лады, понял. Спасибо. По сути же static_cast<Base2 &&> это и есть std::forward<Base2>. А вот действительно интересно: А forward может не заинлайниться?

И еще раз спасибо. Не знал, что есть и такой синтаксис (*this).Base2. В подсказке после . не было вариантов с именами предков. Но если написать, то компилируется.

@HalturinEvgeniy "По сути же static_cast<Base2 &&> это и есть std::forward<Base2>" Технически да, но это здорово сбивает с толку. "А forward может не заинлайниться?" В дебаге может и может, в релизе вряд ли. "Не знал, что есть и такой синтаксис (*this).Base2" Это скорее надо читать как *this . Base2::Data().

"Это скорее надо читать как..." Ага, я понял. Я просто не знал, что можно через . обращаться к структуре предка. В подсказках не было, и не попадалось никогда. А может просто внимания не обращал.

дошло до меня наконец то, что значило Ваше *this . Base2::Data() Спять ложусь сейчас и дошло ))) Это как бы обычный .Data(), но перед Data указывается чей именно это Data. . Петя vs . Иванов Петя. Полное имя метода, короче
